Suppose a colony of cells starts with 10 cells, and their number triples every hour. After how many hours will there be 500 cells?
I thought it would be log(500), which gives approximately 2.69897. I know that there could be alternative forms of the answer, but for the life of me, I don't understand how they arrive at this supposedly correct answer.
I included a screenshot of the multiple choices available and the answer the site indicates as correct with the check mark.
Is it correct or did they make a mistake?


The equation that you can form is
$$
10 \cdot 3^t = 500
$$
I'm sure everyone can solve for $t$ from that.

Here’s a longer explanation that might help you understand the reason for the steps.
You know that the colony starts with $10$ cells, and triples every hour. So after one hour, the number of cells would be:
$10\cdot3$
After two hours:
$10\cdot3\cdot3$ $\rightarrow$ $10\cdot3^2$
After three hours:
$10\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3$ $\rightarrow$ $10\cdot3^3$
Now that we see the pattern, we can condense it into the expression $10\cdot3^t$, where $t$ is the number of hours passed. This allows $10$ to be multiplied by an additional $3$ every time another hour passes.
Lastly, we want to figure out how long it takes for $500$ cells to exist. In other words, we need the value of $t$ where $10\cdot3^t=500$ (as said in Mattie P’s comment).
$3^t=50$ $\Leftarrow$ (divided both sides by ten)
$t=\log_3(50)$ $\Leftarrow$ (we did $\log_3$ because $3$ is the base whose exponent we want to figure out)
So the final answer is $\log_3(50)$.

Well it is not clear from the problem that the equation is also true when $t$ is not an integer, is it?

I use the equation:
10*3^t=500
So I divide both sides by 10 which gives me 3^t=50. Since I have to solve for t, I take the logarithm of 3^t.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
